# reading data from mongodb atlas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, azure, pymongo

I am trying to read data from mongoDB from python language . Different codes  I had tried but none works

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pprint import pprint

client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster1-hc9jb.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.sample_airbnb
collection = db.listingsAndReviews.find()
for inventory in collection:
     pprint(inventory)
```

got this error

```
runfile('C:/Users/Umer MiB/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Umer MiB/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-58c4aa2d2ef7>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Umer MiB/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Umer MiB/.spyder-py3')

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Umer MiB/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 19, in <module>
    for inventory in collection:

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1156, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1050, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1810, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1763, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1796, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 490, in get_server_session
    None)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 209, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))

ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed
```

I've followed the solutions describing `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343409/how-do-i-retrieve-and-print-pymongo-cursor-cursor-objects` but none works
I also followed `https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/read/` but failed to read

Comment: Your code works for me with python 3.7, pymongo 3.7.0 and dnspython 1.16.0. Could you please check in MongoDB Atlas that you have the correct user & password in the Security > Database Access menu and also check in the Security > Network Access menu that you IP address is correctly white listed?
If this is correctly white listed, you should be able to ping any of your 3 nodes like this: `ping: cluster0-shard-00-00-abcde.mongodb.net`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code but first replace: **replace_this_with_user_name, replace_this_with_pass, replace_this_with_database_name, replace_this_with_your_collection_name**.
Also before do anything just create a new user with very simple password (no special char because you will need to encode them) and try with the new user to access your database. See more for this [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/#add-database-users).

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

#connect with MongoDB
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://replace_this_with_user_name:replace_this_with_pass@replace_this_with_cluster_name.miobx.mongodb.net/replace_this_with_database_name?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

db = client.get_database('replace_this_with_database_name')
records = db.replace_this_with_your_collection_name

#print your collection
print(list(records()))
```

Maybe you will need to install some packages also like:

```
pip install pymongo[srv]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the above it worked for me after I did:

pip install dnspython

and changed 2 lines:

```
client = MongoClient("replace with MONGODB_URI")
db = client['replace_this_with_database_name']
```

The above was necessary for my Nightscout data after migration to MongodbAtlas.